# Using an Additional Lookup Column Value in a Calculated Column

Tags: 2010, lookup-column, calculated-column

I have a lookup column based on another list's description (a 'Category' list) and have ticked the other list's 'Category ID' column to be shown at the same time (I note that this is a manually 'category ID' column and not the auto-assigned item ID).

I would like to use this additional column's value in a calculated column (the idea being that the user selects the Category via it's description lookup column and the category ID is appended to the current list's item identifier). However I'm not sure how to reference the additional column in the calculated field's formula builder and it doesn't appear in the 'insert column' list.

Is this possible with the formula builder (i.e. along the lines of '*=[Cat ID] + "-" + [Number]*') or will I need to use javascript to set the field value?

(I've tried the above example - where Cat ID is the additional column's local name in the list - but with no joy)

Thanks!

Comment: but you can do it with a custom Workflow on SharePoint Designer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you're only able to use the following field types in a calculated field formula:

- Yes/No
- Calculated (as long as it isn't the current one)
- Choice
- Number/Currency
- DateTime
- Text

Lookups cannot be used.

Comment: Aww drats. I was hoping that wasn't the case. In any case, thanks for the answer!